# How to make selenium recognize a search with an apostrophe in it

Tags: python, selenium

I made a script that uploads student grades and comments from my google sheet into D2L. 
To get selenium to enter the iframe that has a text box for comment, I search for the first and last name. This worked for me all last year. This year I have names that include ' as a part of a last name, for example james d'arcy. Selenium doesn't like this.

Is there an easy way to make the apostrophe be recognized? or maybe a way to not need an exact match for my search?

```
 for i in toplist:  # copies and pastes in comments 
        icnFeedback = "//a[contains(@title,'"+ i[0]+"') and @class='d2l-imagelink']" #i[0] is students name, looking that it is contained in title. 
        comments = i[1]  # i[1] is student comment

        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, icnFeedback)))
        myElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(icnFeedback)   # find user by names
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", myElement)   #clicks the feedback button
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

It just keeps searching, but the apostrophe messes up the search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this might be happening because you are using single quotes to both contain your string (`i[0]`) and there is a single quote within the string itself. When this happens the query loses its structure.

```py
fake_ln = "las'tname"
xpath = "//a[contains(@title,'"+ fake_ln +"') and @class='d2l-imagelink']"
print(xpath)
# outputs: //a[contains(@title,'las'tname') and @class='d2l-imagelink']
```

This is a problem because now instead of only the last name being in quotes you also put `) and @class=` into quotes as well.

Try this:

```py
icnFeedback = '//a[contains(@title,"'+ i[0]+'") and @class="d2l-imagelink"]'
```